# Setting up apt package manager in Yocto image

Tags: debian, apt, yocto

I have created a filesystem image using Yocto by setting `EXTRA_IMAGE_FEATURES = "package-management"` and `CORE_IMAGE_EXTRA_INSTALL += "apt"` in Yocto's configuration file. The image is successfully built and running.

Now here comes the issue! I have added following string in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/custom.list` to setup debian repo:

`deb [ arch=powerpc ] http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian jessie main`

But when I run `apt-get update`, I get following errors:

```
Ign http://ftp.us.debian.org jessie InRelease
Get:1 http://ftp.us.debian.org jessie Release.gpg [2373 B]
Hit http://ftp.us.debian.org jessie Release
Ign http://ftp.us.debian.org jessie Releaseled in /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/.
Get:2 http://ftp.us.debian.org jessie/main powerpc Packages [7512 kB]
Get:3 http://ftp.us.debian.org jessie/main Translation-en [3846 kB]
Err http://ftp.us.debian.org jessie/main powerpc Packages

Err http://ftp.us.debian.org jessie/main powerpc Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 208.80.154.15 80]
Ign http://ftp.us.debian.org jessie/main Translation-en
Fetched 2373 B in 10s (226 B/s)
W: GPG error: http://ftp.us.debian.org jessie Release: Could not execute 'gpgv' to verify signature (is gpgv installed?)
W: Failed to fetch http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/dists/jessie/main/binary-powerpc/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 208.80.154.15 80]

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Here I noticed that that apt is trying to download `Packages` rather than `Packages.gz` file. Can someone suggest how to force `apt` to fetch gzipped file rather then uncompressed Packages file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Answering Your Question

Referencing [this post](https://askubuntu.com/a/455775) and the [apt manpage](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/apt/apt-get.8.en.html) for Debian you can use this command to force `apt` to prefer the `gz` file compression format:

```
apt-get -o Acquire::CompressionTypes::Order::=gz update
```

## Solving your Issue

It however looks like that the real issue is that your repositories do not have a working gpg key mechanism  as shown in the error:

> ```
> W: GPG error: http://ftp.us.debian.org jessie Release: Could not execute 'gpgv' to verify signature (is gpgv installed?)
> ```

To solve this, I am referencing [this post](https://askubuntu.com/q/41605) which appears to be related to this error.

You will need to run the following commands as root(sudo) to help fix your repositories:

```
rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
apt-get clean
apt-get update
```

Read through [the linked post](https://askubuntu.com/q/41605) related to this issue to see if there is anything else you can try. However your error also mentions that you are potentially missing `gpgv`. [Here is a link](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/gpgv) to download the version of `gpgv` you will need. Remember to verify what version of Debian you are using and what architecture your system is using first. Furthermore, you will need to also verify you have met all the required dependencies. Download and then install those packages like so:

```
wget [url of package you wish to download]
dpkg -i [Name of Package].deb
```

And for installing libraries you fetch the needed lib file and run:

```
mv [Desired Library] /usr/lib
ldconfig -n -v /usr/lib
```

This should solve that error once you have acquired all the necessary packages and libraries to install `gpgv`.

## Upon further inspection of your post you have an Additional error:

> ```
> W: Failed to fetch http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/dists/jessie/main/binary-powerpc/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 208.80.154.15 80]
> ```

It appears that that repository does not exist, giving you a 404 error. On the [Debian Wiki concerning the Jessie release and PowerPC architecture](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/) it should still be up. Try changing your mirror in your sources.list to better follow the [Official Debian Wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/SourcesList?action=show&redirect=sources.list) recommendations.

## Conclusion

Yes you can set `apt` to use a specific format. You also appear to have other problems with your question. I have tried to address them as best I can. Please comment if there are any inconsistencies or errors you are encountering. As always, corrections concerning misinformation or misconceptions in my answer are welcome. Best of Luck!

Comment: Thanks @kemotep for this detailed answer. It worked like a charm!